# proper way to use GNU/Linux read() function

Tags: c++, c, linux, pointers

in the man pages of GNU/Linux the read function is described with following synopsis:

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

I would like to use this function to read data from a socket or a serial port. If the `count` is greater than one, the pointer supplied in the function argument will point to the last byte that was read from the port in the memory so pointer decrement is necessary for bringing the pointer to the first byte of data. This is dangerous because using it in a language like C++ with it's dynamic memory allocation of containers based on their size and space needs could corrupt data at the point of return from `read()` function. I thought of using a C-style array instead of a pointer. Is this the correct approach? If not, what is the correct way to do this? The programming language I'm using is C++.

**EDIT:**

The code that caused the described situation is as follows:

`QSerialPort` class was used to configure and open the port with following parameters:

- Baudrate of 115200
- 8 data bits
- No parity
- One stop bit
- No flow control

and for the reading part as long as the stackoverflow is concerned the read is performed exactly like this:

A `std::vector` containing a number of `struct`s defined this way:

```
struct DataMember 
{
    QString name;
    size_t  count;
    char *buff;
}
```

then within a while loop until the end of the mentioned `std::vector` is reached, a `read()` is performed based on `count` member variable of the said `struct` and the data is stored in the same `struct`'s buff:

```
ssize_t nbytes = read(port->handle(), v.at(i).buff, v.at(i).count);
```

and then the data is printed on the console. In my test case as long as the data is one byte the value printed is correct but for more than one byte the value displayed is the last value that was read from the port plus some garbage values. I don't know why is this happening. Note that the correct result is obtained when the `char *buff` is changed to `char buff[count]`.

Comment: I am not really sure why you think the pointer needs to move? The `count` parameter tells the function how large the array pointed to by `buf` is so that it won't overwrite the end of the array.

Comment: The pointer points to the first byte of data (if any data is read).

Comment: @Galik because that actually happened. after reading more than one byte the pointer always pointed to the last byte so i had to decrement it to point to the beginning of the data.

Comment: For most purposes, you'll write something like: `char buffer[1024]; ssize_t nbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));` and you'll look at the `nbytes` value to distinguish between errors (`-1`), EOF (`0`) and data (`> 0`).  The data will have been placed in the C-style array, starting at the address `&buffer[0]` aka `buffer`.  The value in `nbytes` need not be 1024; it won't be bigger than 1024 (assuming you use that limit).  You may prefer a bigger buffer size (like 4 KiB or 8 Kib).  The data will not be null-terminated, in general.

Comment: @WilliamPursell actually that is what I thought but in practice this didn't happen.

Comment: @MoKi Can you post some code that shows the problem you are describing? So others can duplicate the problem you are encountering.

Comment: @Moki Do you use `new` or `malloc` or other function to allocate memory for `char *buff`.  If yes, can you show how do you do it?

Comment: Indeed, if the only change you are making to the code is modifying the declaration of buff, then the problem is that you are not allocating space for buff and you are experiencing undefined behavior.  In other words, the bug is in your code, not in the behavior of `read`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know why is this happening.

But I know. `char *` is just a pointer, but that pointer needs to be initialized to something before you can use it. Without doing so you're invoking undefined behavior and everything might happen.

Instead of the `size_t count;` and `char *buff` elements you should just use a `std::vector<char>`, before making the read call, resize it to the number of bytes you want to read, then take the address of the first element of that vector and pass that to read:

```
struct fnord {
    std::string name;
    std::vector data;
};
```

and use it like this; note that using `read` requires some additional work to properly deal with signal and error conditions.

```
size_t readsomething(int fd, size_t count, fnord &f)
{
    // reserve memory
    f.data.reserve(count);

    int rbytes = 0;
    int rv;
    do {
        rv = read(fd, &f.data[rbytes], count - rbytes);
        if( !rv ) {
            // End of File / Stream
            break;
        }
        if( 0 > rv ) {
            if( EINTR == errno ) {
                // signal interrupted read... restart
                continue;
            }
            if( EAGAIN == errno
             || EWOULDBLOCK == errno ) {
                // file / socket is in nonblocking mode and
                // no more data is available.
                break;
            }
            // some critical error happened. Deal with it!
            break;
        }
        rbytes += rv;
    } while(rbytes < count);
    return rbyteS;
}
```

---

#### Looking at your first paragraph of *gibberish*:

> If the count is greater than one, the pointer supplied in the function argument will point to the last byte that was read from the port in the memory

What makes you think so? This is not how it works. Most likely you passed some invalid pointer that wasn't properly initialized. Anything can happen.

> so pointer decrement is necessary for bringing the pointer to the first byte of data.

Nope. *That's not how it works.*

> This is dangerous because using it in a language like C++ with it's dynamic memory allocation of containers based on their size and space needs could corrupt data at the point of return from read() function.

*Nope*. **That's not how it works!**

C and C++ are an explicit languages. Everything happens in plain sight and nothing happens without *you* (the programmer) explicitly requesting it. No memory is allocated without *you* requesting this to happen. It can either be an explicit `new`, some RAII, automatic storage or the use of a container. But nothing happens "out of the blue" in C and C++. There's no built-in garbage collection^1 in C nor C++. Objects don't move around in memory or resize without you explicitly coding something into your program that makes this happen.

---

[1]: There are GC libraries you can use, but those *never* will stomp onto anything that can be reached by code that's executing. Essentially garbage collector libraries for C and C++ are memory leak detectors, which will free memory that can no longer be reached by normal program flow.

Answer (score 3):

> If the count is greater than one, the pointer supplied in the function argument will point to the last byte that was read from the port in the memory

No. The pointer is passed to the `read()` method by value, so it is therefore completely and utterly impossible for the value to be any different after the call than it was before, regardless of the count.

> so pointer decrement is necessary for bringing the pointer to the first byte of data.

The pointer already points to the first byte of data. No decrement is necessary.

> This is dangerous because using it in a language like C++ with it's dynamic memory allocation of containers based on their size and space needs could corrupt data at the point of return from read() function.

This is all nonsense based on an impossibility.

You are mistaken about all this.

Comment: do you think I would ask this question if this situation would not happen? using C-style arrays as pointed in comments by Jonathan solved the problem and the data was exactly as I expected but with pointer I could see my expected data exist in the memory but the pointer is not pointing to the beginning of it.

Comment: The situation you described is physically, logically, and semantically impossible. *Ergo* it did not happen as you described it. If you post some code you may get told what really happened. Mere assertion won't cut it.

Comment: I've updated the description. please comment if more details are needed.

Answer (score 2):

> In my test case as long as the data is one byte the value printed is correct but for more than one byte the value displayed is the last value that was read from the port plus some garbage values.

From the read(2) manpage:

> On  success,  the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), 
>   and the file position is advanced by this number.  It is not an error if this number is 
>   smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer 
>   bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or 
>   because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was interrupted 
>   by a signal.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.  In this case it 
>   is left unspecified whether the file position (if any) changes.

In the case of pipes, sockets and character devices (that includes serial ports) and a blocking file descriptor (default) read will, in practice, not wait for the full count. In your case read() blocks until a byte comes in on the serial port and returns. That is why in the output the first byte is correct and the rest is garbage (uninitialized memory). You have to add a loop around the read() that repeats until count bytes have been read if you need the full count.